# Dynamic fetching of file url from Firebase using dom-repeat in Polymer via computed binding

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer-1.0, firebase-storage

I'm having problems with displaying images using the dom-repeat in Polymer. I use Firebase Storage to store the images.

```
<firebase-query id="productsQuery"
                data="{{products}}"
                limit-to-first="2"></firebase-query>
```

The path of the above element is updated dynamically and works fine.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[products]]" index-as="index">
    <paper-card image="[[computePhotoURL(item.$key)]]" heading="[[item.name]]">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="shop-name">[[shopName]]</p>
        <small>Php [[item.price]]</small>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>
```

From the above element everything is working fine, they display info but with the computed function, it does not return the url properly.

Here's the computed binding code:

```
computePhotoURL: function(key) {
    var photo;
    firebase.storage()
            .ref('users/' + this.data[0].$key + '/products/' + key)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then( function(url) {
              photo = url;
              return url;
            }.bind(this)).catch( function(error) {
              console.log('there was an error');
            });
    return photo;
  }
```

By logging the url from the above function it displays the correct url from the firebase storage but it doesn't seem to return the proper value binded in the paper-card's image attribute.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance :)

I tried changing it into

```
computePhotoURL: function(key) {
    var photo;
    firebase.storage()
            .ref('users/' + this.data[0].$key + '/products/' + key)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then( function(url) {
              photo = url;
              console.log(photo);
              //logs correct url
            }.bind(this)).catch( function(error) {
              console.log('there was an error');
            });
    console.log('photo', photo);
    //logs undefined
    return photo;
  }
```

And it logs undefined first before the correct url. So the photo variable was returned before it was changed. Help on how to fix this? Not good with JS this much :(

Comment: You "return url;" before the bind completes. So it never "return photo;"

Comment: I did try to remove the 'return url;' and logging the photo outside the 'then function' is null also :( @zerohero

Comment: show .getDownloadURL() function

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @zerohero

Comment: I did tried logging and found out that the photo variable was returned first before it was changed from getDownloadURL function @zerohero

Comment: delete return photo; then and try?

Comment: Tried it still not working :(

Comment: Is there any way that I can attach a callback listener like 'ready' when an element is stamped in the dom-repeat template to use the 'event' object? It's what i need as an alternative, with that I will be able to reference the changes directly to target. e.g) <paper-card on-attached="callbackFunction"></paper-card>   I tried this on the top but it does not fire :( thanks for the help @zerohero

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just remembered to post the answer:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[products]]" index-as="index">
    <paper-card id="card[[index]]" image="[[computePhotoURL(item.$key, index)]]" heading="[[item.name]]">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p class="shop-name">[[shopName]]</p>
        <small>Php [[item.price]]</small>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>
```

So as you can see I added an index parameter to the computed binding function and specified an ID for the paper-card concatenated with the index to differentiate the others.

```
computePhotoURL: function(key, index) {
    var id = '#card' + index;
    firebase.storage()
            .ref('users/' + this.data[0].$key + '/products/' + key)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then( function(url) {
              this.$$(id).image = url;
            }.bind(this)).catch( function(error) {
              console.log('there was an error', error);
            });
  }
```

And so whenever the image url will be fetched, it will reference the image attribute based from the id generated from the dom-repeater using the this.$$(query) :)

Thanks for the help guys esp. @zerohero